# Where is the Apex URL builder?

Tags: apex

Using `apex:outputLink` or `URLFOR(target, id, params)` is great in Visualforce. But in Apex land I always see people looping through lists using `EncodingUtil.urlEncode(param, 'UTF-8')`.

If [System.Url](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_url.htm) doesn't have a parameter parser or builder, what's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This capability is available using the `PageReference` class. You can use the same mechanism to build query strings or parse the parameters out of one, without loops and a whole lotta script statements.

**Parse an RFC 3986 URL query string**

```
String query = '?password=Hunter2dog%26cat&username=user%40example.com';

System.PageReference pageReference = new System.PageReference('/' + query);
Map<String,String> parameters = pageReference.getParameters();

String password = parameters.get('password'); //Hunter2dog&cat
String username = parameters.get('username'); //user@example.com
```

**Build an RFC 3986 URL query string**

```
Map<String,String> parameters = new Map<String,String>{
  'password' => 'Hunter2dog&cat',
  'username' => 'user@example.com'
};

System.PageReference pageReference = new System.PageReference('');
pageReference.getParameters().putAll(parameters);

String query = pageReference.getUrl();
//?password=Hunter2dog%26cat&username=user%40example.com
```

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt